# Git warning "encountered old-style '/home/user/.gitignore' that should be '%(prefix)/home/user/.gitignore'"

Tags: git

Using git version 2.35.1.windows.2, all Git invocations include this warning at least once:

```
PS C:\Users\BoppreH\Desktop\source\keyboard> git status
warning: encountered old-style '/home/boppreh/.gitignore' that should be '%(prefix)/home/boppreh/.gitignore'
On branch new_core
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/new_core'.
[...]
```

Sometimes multiple times:

```
PS C:\Users\BoppreH\Desktop\source\keyboard> git pull
warning: encountered old-style '/home/boppreh/.gitignore' that should be '%(prefix)/home/boppreh/.gitignore'
warning: encountered old-style '/home/boppreh/.gitignore' that should be '%(prefix)/home/boppreh/.gitignore'
warning: encountered old-style '/home/boppreh/.gitignore' that should be '%(prefix)/home/boppreh/.gitignore'
warning: encountered old-style '/home/boppreh/.gitignore' that should be '%(prefix)/home/boppreh/.gitignore'
warning: encountered old-style '/home/boppreh/.gitignore' that should be '%(prefix)/home/boppreh/.gitignore'
Already up to date.
```

Which is confusing, because I'm on Windows and there's no `.gitignore` file in my home folder.

What is causing this warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the latest `git` releases for Windows, prepending `%(prefix)` on any root file-reference is suggested.

Otherwise you will get the warning that you are referring to. The amount of times that you will get it depends on the `git` command that you are running. Which effectively reflects the number of times that such references in your `.gitconfig` file are parsed.

I believe if you update the offending line as below, you will not get the warning message.

```sh
[core]
   excludesfile = %(prefix)/home/boppreh/.gitignore
```

BTW with [Git for Windows v2.35.3](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/main/ReleaseNotes.md#git-for-windows-v2353-release-notes) there was a bug-fix released that was related to `%(prefix)` when using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Might be related with your case if you add the prefix and you are still getting the warning.

Answer (score 6):

A simple `~` in the file name solved this for me, with the added benefit that it works on Windows and Unix.

```
[core]
  excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

The warning should be gone.

Comment: This worked for me too while other solutions did not. Not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

The user configuration file at `~/.gitconfig` contained the following entry:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /home/boppreh/.gitignore
```

So the problem is that I assumed the leading slash made the path absolute (it doesn't), and I transferred a .gitconfig file from a Linux machine without the matching .gitignore file.

My solution was to remove the offending line.

Answer (score 1):

For me help, it is:

```
git config core.protectNTFS false
```