# git warnings "encountered old-style" for lokal repository

Tags: git, samba

i have a git repository on a share from a raspberry pi (over samba with docker-compose). Im try to set up the repository to a subfolder "openhabDocker" because i cant get it work within the root folder of the share.

Now when im in VS Code in the git extension i see no more changes even if I add new files.
When i refresh the git extension i get this warning:

```
Git: warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
```

but i dont find any config where the path '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' is set.

Also in the output i find multiple of these messages. '//openhab/openhab_conf' is even no more present in vs code

```
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
warning: encountered old-style '//openhab/openhab_conf/' that should be '%(prefix)///openhab/openhab_conf/'
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
```

Any hints? Im stuck and out of ideas

**Update**: with a new install of the windows git client i was able to process all necessary git commands.
So last thing would be to get rid of all these warnings coming with every git command.

**Update 2**:this is the output:

```
PS X:\openhabDocker> git remote -v   
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
warning: encountered old-style '//openhab/openhab_conf/' that should be '%(prefix)///openhab/openhab_conf/'
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/' that should be '%(prefix)///192.168.178.99/openhab_docker/'
origin  N:/openhabDocker.git (fetch)
origin  N:/openhabDocker.git (push)
```

none of the listed paths are within the git config.

Comment: These are probably somewhere in the .git directory which VSCode is probably ignoring. Possibly they're remotes (check with `git remote -v`) or in .git/config. My guess is the repository was cloned using Windows style network path rather than URLs.

Comment: there is none of the paths listed in the config of the repository, see "Update 2". Is there 
 any global config for the git client? Im on Windows 10. I also deleted the whole .git folder several times while trying to get it work. also strange that i get the same warning several times

Comment: Try `git config --list --show-origin` to list all your config options and see if there's anything there. See if [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70998844/git-warning-encountered-old-style-home-user-gitignore-that-should-be-pre).

Comment: Thats it! i thought these warnings have to relate to the actual repository but in the global config file where the listed paths under the tag [safe]. Thanks a lot, finally a clean git setup!